# MySQL Group by consecutive values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have rate_history table, with data for each employee and his rate changes over job positions. I want to get job position changes for each employee in single query. Selected job is one with most current update in consecutive rows. Note, same job position can be re assigned to an employee over time.

```
id job_id updated
1    1    01-01-2015
2    1    01-02-2015
3    2    01-01-2015
4    2    01-03-2015
5    2    01-02-2015
6    1    01-01-2015
```

result should be:

```
id job_id updated
1    1    01-01-2015
3    2    01-01-2015
6    1    01-02-2015
```

Comment: whya re missing id's 1, 3 and 5. Do you need latest job for each employess? If not, can you please more verbose in the question

Comment: @Santhosh sorry, I've edited question. I want every job position change took place

Comment: @dzona `id` is the employee id ?

Comment: "I want to get job position changes for each employee in single query." Can you explain this. Do you need latest job for each employee or do you need the latest employee assigned to each job? What combination you need

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard no, ID is table row ID. Presume we already filtered result by employee, or this is single employee tabe

Comment: @Santhosh I want to get every record when job position have changed (lowest update time of each consecutive set)

Comment: How, if at all, does the `updated` date fit into this?  Is it in fact sensible that row 1 and row 6 in the base table have the same `job_id` *and* the same `updated` date?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've edited question. Updated, created, or any other column, it doesn't matter, i just want to use that column to order result and do consecutive group by, leaving only "heading" row for each consecutive group

Comment: My question is exactly about whether you want to use the `updated` row to identify the transitions, which still is not clear to me.  Since row 1 and row 6 of the base table differ only in the `id` column, does that mean the `updated` date is irrelevant to identifying the job transitions you want to find?  If not, then what is the logic?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I want to use ``updated`` column to identify transition

Comment: Fine, I suspected as much, but you still haven't explained.  My best guess at an interpretation of the data presented is that the employee held `job_id`s 1 (twice) and 2 on 01-01-2015, held `job_id`s 1 (once) and 2 on 01-02-2015, and held only `job_id` 2 on 01-03-2015.  I am at a loss as to how that corresponds to your desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay, here is my fiddle link based on my understanding on the output you provided,

You can use row number(not available with mysql but using roundabout) and then getting records which are having job_ids not same as previous records.

[Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f3a0/8)

```
select t1.id
     , t1.job_id
     , t1.updatedate
     , t2.rn as rnt2
  from temprwithrn as t1
  left 
  join temprwithrn as t2
    on t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
 where t1.job_id <> t2.job_id or t2.job_id is null
```

Comment: I don't want extra tables to be used

Comment: Use that as a subquery

Comment: Are you sure that your data set is properly representative of the problem?

Comment: yes, I get same outputs as given in question and it always gives the record first changed compared to the previous records

Comment: Short and sweet. Nice.