# MySQL: Group by only connected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way in MySQL to group by "only" connected (serialized) rows in table:

ex, table:

```
id     user_id     score
1         1        100
2         1        100
3         2        100
5         1        100
7         1        100
8         3        100
9         4        100
10        5        100
10        5        100
11        1        100
```

Group by "user_id" and `sum(score)` but only for followed rows with same "user_id", expected results:

```
user_id     score
    1        200
    2        100
    1        200
    3        100
    4        100
    5        200
    1        100
```

Test Query:

```
select t.user_id,sum(t.score)
from table t
group by t.user_id
```

Will return something like:

```
user_id     score
    1        500
    2        100
    3        100
    4        100
    5        200
```

Thx, for help,

Comment: You can use a strategy similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158039/mysql-group-by-consecutive-values)

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select user_id,sum(score) score
    -> from
    -> (select user_id,score,
    ->  if(user_id <> @p , @block:=@block+1,@block:=@block) block,
    ->  @p:=user_id
    -> from(select @block:=0,@p:=0) vars, t
    -> order by id,user_id
    -> ) s
    -> group by block
    ->  ;
+---------+-------+
| user_id | score |
+---------+-------+
|       1 |   200 |
|       2 |   100 |
|       1 |   200 |
|       3 |   100 |
|       4 |   100 |
|       5 |   200 |
|       1 |   100 |
+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

Comment: Just work fine, wondering if there're more optimized solution (apply on very large table),

Answer (score -1):

As it's mysql, stick in an extra `group by` for the scores

```
select userid, sum(score)
from MyTable
group by userid, score
```

For the downvoters, [check it](http://rextester.com/PTAYCM40083)

Comment: Not my downvote, but if you want to solve this, look into gaps and islands.

Comment: This is far away from requirements, won't work and score will not be always 100

Comment: @mwafi Check the test, it performs exactly as the requirements describe, or are your requirements poorly defined?

Comment: @JohnHC this solution could only work if score always be a fixed number, which isn't described in the Qs (Score could be variable 90,80,100 .. etc)

Comment: @mwafi No, this is based on whatever the scores may be, the insert statement (where you see the 100s) merely sets up some sample data.